# PHP Template class / engine processing time

Tags: php, template-engine

I want to learn a bit more about OOP within PHP. So i decided that i would build my own **MVC framework** and a simple application running on this framework.

There are a lot of great tutorials out there on this thing called the world wide web but **most of them write** the template / **view class as below**.

For example:

```
$haystack = file_get_contents($this->file);

foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
    $needle = "<@$key>";
    $output = str_replace($needle, $value, $haystack);
}
```

**I was wondering** if this isn't **way to heavy for what it accomplishes**, sure you get real fancy templates but **doens't it take ages to process** to first **read** the document, **store** it as a variable, **search** it for **each** variable and then replacing it and rendering the content.

Or **are my thoughts way off here?**

Hope someone can shed some light on this. Since a lot of people take this approach which doesn't feel right. So is this the right way and if not, what is the right way for a view class or template engine without compromising on performance?

Comment: Why cannot you just modify [this](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) approach ?

Comment: +1 for that article. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to run benchmarks to get a definitive answer, but I would expect to get the best performance by simply making your templates PHP files, i.e. set your template variables in a local context and `include` the "template" file there directly.  The benchmark [site has changed and does not offer the benchmark anymore (mention removed)] certainly indicates that it's faster than most template engines (not surprising, as the interpreter does all the parsing for you).  Of course, many people discourage using PHP files as templates because it doesn't enforce any separation of concerns - your template *is* a source file.  It's a workable approach, but it does put all of the burden on the developer to not do the wrong thing in the templates.

As far as the actual performance of the `str_replace()` approach, it's certainly not optimal, but it's probably not as bad as you think.  For a low-traffic site, it would probably work fine.  For a larger site with decent traffic, probably not so much.  Aside from the performance aspect, this approach is just too simple to be useful for anything non-trivial - there's no caching, no output escaping, no control structures, no macros, etc.

This type of templating is really only useful as an exercise.  It's basically the simplest possible case for a template system.  Building a production-ready template engine is going to require some actual parsing, a caching strategy, and significantly more features than this to make it workable and reasonably performant.